# Insert media image in detail view

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, view-helpers, urlimageviewhelper

I'm using TYPO3 9.5.3 and the sf_books extension to manage books.

I inserted book on BE with image cover for the book item.

I get this error on the singleView (detail) :

```
The argument "image" was registered with type "object", but is of type "string" in view helper "TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\ImageViewHelper".
```

When I check the template file I find this code supposed displays an image :

```
<f:image image="{book.cover}" maxWidth="200" alt="{book.title}"/>
```

How can I change this code the solve the error and display the cover book ?

Answer (score 1):

if you have a look here https://github.com/evoWeb/sf_books/blob/develop/Resources/Private/Templates/Book/Show.html you can see, that the problem should be fixed. The {book.cover} gets iterated and used as {cover} in the

If you experience futher errors, feel free to hand in issues in the tracker https://github.com/evoWeb/sf_books/issues and they will be covered.

Comment: Thanks, I used it, but i get this error `The argument "each" was registered with type "array", but is of type "string" in view helper "TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\ViewHelpers\ForViewHelper".`

Comment: Without the context i cant help you. what exact version of the extension? What template folder and file is it? What field? Where is the file stored(in sf_books or your sitepackage)?

This problem should be solved in version 5.2.2